# Remove option not working in IE11 for dropdownlist

Tags: jquery, razor

This works in all browsers but IE11. It seems like the dropdown list has the right values however the display of the items in the dropdown list is coming from a `ul` with `li` tags with the fields.

I have a dropdown list in a Razor view. I remove these which works fine in Firefox, Edge and Chrome using the `remove()` option in jQuery.

However when I inspect the element the select list has the options removed however the `ul` that gets created does not

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap `this` to work in IE browser, e.g.:

```
$('#li-id').on('click', function() {
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: if (et.EnergySourceImpact.LEmissionFactor == 0.000000)
                    {
                        @:$("#DisclosedValues_@(i)__Unit option[value='@((int)Units.L)']").remove();
                                                                                                                                }   So I am removing the dropdown list based on values in document ready